# Entity Framework Core Exception "System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, debian, .net-core

I am trying to run my dotnet core application on my debian 8 server. My app is divided in two.

- The console app
- The database access dll

I followed the instruction to install the runtime on the Microsoft DotNet website.

When I start my console app, Entity Framework Core throws me an exception.

Exception Message:

> The type initializer for 'System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility' threw an exception.

Inner Exception Message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's m            anifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

This is how my app is configured:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyTitle>Project.Login</AssemblyTitle>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>Project.Login</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>Project.Login</PackageId>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;win7-x64;osx.10.10-x64;ubuntu.14.04-x64;ubuntu.14.10-x64;ubuntu.15.04-x64;ubuntu.15.10-x64;ubuntu.16.04-x64;ubuntu.16.10-x64;centos.7-x64;debian.8-x64;fedora.23-x64;fedora.24-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Core\Project.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Database\Project.Database.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Ether.Network" Version="1.1.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And my Project.Database configuration :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.6</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>Project.Database</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>Project.Database</PackageId>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.1</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.6-IR31" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I tried with differents runtimes and SDK and still the same issue.

Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

I've added the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` 1.1 package to my `Project.Database` project and deleted the `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` and remove the two lines :

```
<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

from my apps project configuration.

It now works.