# Why do I get a System.IO.FileLoadException for the System.Runtime.InteropServices assembly when using SqlClient in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, sqlclient

I developed a .NET Core application.
The solution consists of netstandard1.6 from the library and the console application netcoreapp1.1.
Both projects use SqlClient.
If I do publish on Windows and run, then everything will work out well.
If I run on Linux then the application crash and an error occurs:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught) --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The type
>   initializer for 'System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility' threw
>   an exception.) ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility' threw
>   an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: **Could not load file
>   or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices**, Version=4.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

*PS: In fact, the server is available and you can connect to it from the application you just created on Linux.*

```
dotnet --info
Product Information:
Version:            1.0.4
Commit SHA-1 hash:  af1e6684fd

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     ubuntu
OS Version:  16.04
OS Platform: Linux
RID:         ubuntu.16.04-x64
Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4
```

Comment: Did you include the nugget in the project or are you reading it form global-packages?

Comment: Please check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363713/entity-framework-core-exception-system-runtime-versioning-binarycompatibility already helps resolve this issue.

Comment: @HansPassant the 1.0.4 tools is the current tooling version that supports .net core 1.1

Comment: @MartinUllrich Thx you! It really helped!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are missing one of the dependcies

Here is my snippet:

```
apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libc6 \
    libcurl3 \
    libgcc1 \
    libgssapi-krb5-2 \
    libicu52 \
    liblttng-ust0 \
    libgdiplus \
    libssl1.0.0 \
    libstdc++6 \
    libunwind8 \
    libuuid1 \
    zlib1g \
```

if not refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363713/entity-framework-core-exception-system-runtime-versioning-binarycompatibility)

Comment: Thank you! Link +1

Comment: @MartinUllrich how to exclude this setting from Visual Studio 2017 without editing csproj file?